# Distribution Commerce Kickstart 1.x - is possbile run Drupal Core 7.61 / PHP 7.2 ? And how

Tags: 7, updating, security

I have small and very simple  Drupal 7 site based on Commerce Kickstart 1.x distribution (originally instalation profile, now "distribution").

The version of distribution is 7.x-1.53. It is last released one.
Further, I have PHP 5.6.39. Website is on common shared hosting. There is not shell e.g. 
MySQL is 5.5.62. Server is apache.

Some particular info regard my site: small multisite (3 sites with the same template and the same modules and with 3 different domains), some 90 modules, every site have approximately 1000 content items.

There is core drupal version 7.60 in this actual Commerce Kickstart 7.x-1.53 (released 18 October 2018)

But I would need the actual drupal core 7.61. It is because I must switch to PHP 7.2 (or 7.3). I would like as soon as possible, because PHP 5.x is not supported from first of January of this year (2019). I can not switch to PHP 7.0 as it is not supported by Drupal, and similarly I can not switch to 7.1 (problems/hosting).

As you can know, there is not a Commerce Kickstart 1.x profile with the Drupal core 7.61 till now. And there is no simple migration from Kickstart 1.x to Kickstart 2.x.

So, what to do now? How make for me to have Drupal compatible with some officially supported PHP version?

I am thinking about following solution:

I could try upgrade only core alone to 7.61 and let Kickstart distribution as it is. 
I would update modules, what need updating, of course.

Could I? Or is there any type of problem in this way?

Notice: I am thinking a bit about "unpicking" the Commerce Kickstart instalation profile from my website completly, but I only found similar thing for another kind of distribution (Community Media Starter Kit), than I have. So I dont now, if it would work?

Thank you

P.S. Problem is not hosting. Hosting is able to give me PHP 7.2 or better. Problem is Kickstart 1.x, what officially is not compatible with 7.2 (regardless Drupal Core now is)

Comment: If you need to use PHP 7.0+ and your host won't allow this, the only solution here would be that you have to migrate to a better host to support this. Why not migrate to Acquia? It could be done in less than a day or two and they let you have PHP 7.2. It is worth moving instead of accumulating risks by never upgrading anything. Pantheon is another option.

Comment: Thank you. I updated question, as there is not problem in hosting, but in Kickstart. Could I personal question: where I can see acquia price list? I can not found it. And have they speak czech language? As my hosting does.

Comment: Is it possible? Just try it out in some isolated environment and you'll see. If not, at the end of the day, you'll need to get your hands dirty and upgrade and migrate everything. Asking for a walkthrough for your problem unfortunately is a too broad question.

Comment: Thank you very much, leymannx. So how I discover, that I cause some hidden problem there now? May be, this my step is bad from some reason (I dont know, it is why I asked) and may be I introduce some hidden problem toi website and in the future there will be e.g. impossible to update the site or anything - and so e.g. need to build the website from scratch? So it is, why I asked (a few days in advance, I know, that I will be testin' "till evening" ;-) )

Comment: Dear leymannx, these domain (distributions (changing, deleting, etc.)) is not probably good documented by documentation, so I have not sure information about how this whole works, so I must ask more experienced ones.